# Get the size of a text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, text-size

I have a problem placing a textView at specified center's x and y coordinates.
Firstly, I tried to set the text in the textView, and to move the view with the width and the height of the view 
[from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653359/how-to-move-a-textview-to-an-x-and-an-y-in-a-relativelayout/6654371#6654371).

But it doesn't work, and I'd like to try something else.
I'd like to know if there is a method to get the size which a specified text will take in my textView? 
I mean, I know the text and the textSize, how can I get the width and the height my textView will take?

Something like the method `(NSString)sizeWithFont;` for those who know iPhone dev.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If your textview is called tv

```
tv.setText("bla");
tv.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
tv.getMeasuredHeight(); //get height
tv.getMeasuredWidth();  //get width
```

More on this (updated): [**How to get width/height of a View**](http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html)

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't actually provide with an accurate measure, specially if you are using a listview

Comment: @nunofmendes you are right. I have extended this topic: check http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html

Comment: @MarceloFilho I dont know why it opens in places and breaks in others. You can try this http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html

Comment: If the text contains any lines that will wrap, you'll need to set the width of the MeasureSpec to AT_MOST to get an accurate height. Example code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20087258/462162

Comment: Your updated link (http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html), is work like a charm. Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 99):

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();

textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
```

`bounds.width()` will give you the accurate width of the text in the Text View.

Comment: Like we love to say here: this should be the answer to the OP. The other answer is the usual old method to measure a view, not a string in a view.

Comment: pathView.getPaint().getTextBounds(pathView.getText().toString(), 0, pathView.getText().length(), bounds);

Comment: does this also works on height of multiline TextView?

Comment: is the result include padding?

Comment: well it's not accurate, I get two lines instead of one when I put text

Answer (score 17):

For some reason the solution of Midverse Engineer does not give me always correct results (at least on some Android versions). The solution of Sherif elKhatib works, but has the side effect of changing MeasuredWidth and Height. This could lead to incorrect positioning of the textView.

My solution:

```
width = textView.getPaint().measureText(text);
metrics = textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics();
height = metrics.bottom - metrics.top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the TextView inner `Paing` class is not so hot when you have multiple lines of text and different paddings. So stop trying to reinvent the wheel. Use `getMeasuredHeight` and `getMeasuredWidth` methods after calling `measure(UNSPECIFIED, UNSPECIFIED)`. Just don't forget to get the new values inside the post, otherwise mostly you'll get a wrong result.

```
tv.setText(state.s);
tv.measure(UNSPECIFIED,UNSPECIFIED);
tv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       Log.d("tv","Height = "+tv.getMeasuredHeight());
       Log.d("tv","Width  = "+tv.getMeasuredWidth());
    }
});
```