# Check if there is not enough room for a String (TextView)

Tags: android

Is it somehow possible to check if a `String`'s length, assigned on `TextView` is of more length than actual device's screen is? In other words, how to check if text doesn't fit on the screen?

What I need is to free some room if text doesn't fit.

Comment: vertically or horizontally(do you want to avoid a ScrollView)? Be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparntly you can call measure on it.

```
textView.setText("bla");
textView.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
textView.getMeasuredHeight(); //get width
textView.getMeasuredWidth();  //get height
```

Taken from question/ answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734301/get-the-size-of-a-text-in-textview)

Then you can use that measurement to compare against screen size.