# Need to make TextView scroll vertically automatically

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to develop an activity that will be part of a simple chat application for a college project. I want to have a setup where I have an `EditText` and a `Button` which when pressed takes the `EditText`'s text and appends it to the contents of a `TextView` in the same activity. That seems to be working fine for me so far but I also want to make it so that when a message is sent to be displayed on the `TextView` if there is not enough space to show the new line of text it will scroll down automatically.

This is what my `onCreate()` in the Activity looks like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1) ;

    //text.setMaxHeight(200);
    text.setSelected(true);
    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edit.getText().length() > 0) {
                text.append(edit.getText() + "\n") ;
                edit.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the relevant section of the Activity's XML layout file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text=""
    android:scrollbars ="vertical"
    android:maxLines="10" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I misunderstanding and is what I want not possible with a textview?

EDIT: Full XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/okString" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="107dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="     " />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have to put the `TextView` inside of a `ScrollView`

Comment: I just did that via the graphical layout interface in eclipse and it seems the application doesn't work now. (getting "Unfortunately, <name> has stopped." as soon as it loads on emu)

Comment: @HugoHidekiYamashita I noticed in the log now it was complaining that it cannot cast from `ScrollView` to `TextView`...
I don't understand why that is happening.

Comment: Can you post full layout xml file and code also?

Comment: Sure, will do asap. The XML that is. There really isn't much more to the code; just the autogenerated onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: check this link for perfect autoscrolling textview in vertical
http://yuvarockers.blogspot.in/2017/04/vertical-autoscrolling-textview-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put vertically scrollable component inside vertically scrollable scrollview, and since your textview is scrollable, i don't see why you need the scrollview in the first place.
Then you can use text.setScrollY(text.getLayout().getHeight()). I'm not sure if it will work, but if it doesn't you can try [Get the size of a text in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734301/get-the-size-of-a-text-in-textview)

Answer (score 2):

```
            String text="Im trying to develop an activity that will be part of a simple chat application for a college project. I want to have a setup where I have an EditText and a Button which when pressed takes the  "
            mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mText.setText(text)
    mText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

XML

```
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="                       
                    " />
```

**Note:**`Instead of storing your text as normal string save it in HTML format which will add line break in your text.`

```
 String text="Im trying to develop an activity that will<br> be part of a simple chat <br>application for a college project. I want to have a setup where I have an EditText and <br>a Button which when pressed takes the  "
```

and then add this line to above code

```
 mText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

***This will return more proper result***

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have inserted a closing tag `</RelativeLayout>` in your xml file, I tried your code and it is working fine on my end. Please try to clean project and rebuilding it again from

```
Project -> Clean
Project -> Build Project
```

EDIT: Can you please try this for layout? Please note that I have removed ScrollView from layout and inserted the line `text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView 
    android:text="    " 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="10">
</TextView>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button 
        android:text="Button1" 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ahh...that fixed the RuntimeException...but it's still not what I want. I want the old text to be pushed up when a new message is sent, if there has been enough messages sent. Y'know, like when a new message comes in on facebook chat or any of many chat systems I imagine.

Comment: Edited the comment with layout file. Please note that the scroll will start working after you have inserted 10 lines into textview as you have set android:maxlines="10"

Comment: Upvoted because you were quite helpful in sorting out some issues but accepting Frane's answer because he gave the one thing that was crucial to what I was looking for; for the text view to scroll up the text _without the user touching it_ when there is more lines that the max line value.