# Text width in a textview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am new to Android..   I have a textview with size 250dp.. I am trying to calculate the text width inside it..  But I could not find any API that returns the actual content width..   Can someone help how it can be done. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the size of a text in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734301/get-the-size-of-a-text-in-textview)

Comment: @alex..   Do you mean getMeasuredWidth()  returns the actual content width?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Paint` object held by the `TextView` to measure the width of the text contents:

```
CharSequence text = textView.getText();
float width = textView.getPaint().measureText(text, 0, text.length());
```

There is also a version that measures the full bounds (left/right/top/bottom) of the text contents:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
CharSequence text = textView.getText();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

//bounds now contains the rect of the actual text string
int width = bounds.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired) answer is completely right.

However, it's useful the reader to know that the text width measure in pixels don't need to be linked with any real content of a `TextView` or `EditText` and isn't restricted to the view widht, so one can simulate if a determinated text fits well in the view before set the view with a text.

Besides, if one uses the whole string you don't need to specify a initial index and a final index (exclusive).

So one can write

```
float width = textView.getPaint().measureText("my favorite fruit is a banana");
```

It works smoothly

Answer (score -2):

There is no API for this.first you have to find the text size and find lenth of string.finally multipl both you will get width of text in textview.