# TextView to show end of String

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a text view that holds a string "Hello World"

Currently because of view size it only shows "Hello Wo"

How can i make it display the end of the string instead e.g. "lo World"?

Comment: Look at your xml, your `layout_width` is probably too small at the moment.

Comment: Please include layout XML

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, it's quite hard to understand what you are asking.

As far as I could understand your question, it's a string manipulation question rather than an Android question. 
If not please update your question and also provide layout XML code.

```
String a="Hello World"; //or whatever your actaul text is a=yourTextView.getText()
String b="Hello Wo"; //As you claim you know the exact length of the displayed text
String c=a.substring(a.length()-b.length(),a.length());

yourTextView.setText(c);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: As this is very rudimentary, I believe you are probably looking an answer to- "how to know the width of displayed text?" if so have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23923053/4382835).

Comment: Question was marked as dup. I found in that post setting ellipsize to start was the solution